# Catalina: How to disable tab(button) in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

Can you disable the keyboard tab button when in Safari?

It is super annoying, when you actually are using tab to switch between application - and when in Safari you keep you little finger at the tab(not pressing) while reading... Then boom you are at the next TAB of the page, just because you relaxed the little finger(only - not the thumb) and pressed the tab button while reading.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring. For me pressing Tab in safari selects between text entry fields. https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keyboard-and-other-shortcuts-cpsh003/mac lists all shortcuts, cmd-down arrow does what I understand what you were referring to.

Comment: Thanks - right, I might only have noticed this on pages where the next tab is somewhere in the bottom. I will try to see I can disable the tab...

Comment: You can try this http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/14/enable-tab-key-navigation-safari/ so the tab key behaves differently.

Comment: Thanks, I actually already disabled "Press tab ..."

Comment: I was thinking enable it. That way it will go the next element on the page and not jump to the textfield at the bottom.

Comment: Ahh, right - that seems to be better. I will accept this if you like?